# Manejo de txt con PHP, ¿Cómo elijo la ruta para guardar un archivo?

Tags: php, web, rutas, txt, desarrollo

Hola a todos espero estén bien, estoy usando PHP para crear archivos TXT, he logrado crear el archivo sin problemas, pero siempre se guarda en la carpeta donde esta mi proyecto, me gustaría que se guardara en descargas o que el usuario elija la ruta donde se pueda almacenar, este es mi código

```
<?php 
$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, "Luis Juarez" . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($file, "Luis Juarez 2" . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
echo "Archivo creado correctamente ";
?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias, espero alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Buenas, en un principio por norma general los buscadores solo te permiten hacer una descarga donde se haya predefinido en la configuración del Sistema Operativo, es decir, el servidor nunca va a poder decir donde guardar el archivo en el cliente, otra cosa es si quieres guardar estos archivos en el servidor, aquí si puedes definir una ruta

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2):

En tu  linea `$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "a");` puedes agregar la ruta de donde deseas guardarlo. ejemplo:

```
$file = fopen("../guardartxtaqui/archivo.txt", "a");
```

recuerda saber en que directorio estas para a si poder moverte sobre los demás directorios con '../' para salirte de un directorio o colocando el nombre el nombre del directorio a mandarlo.

ojo esto solo del lado del servidor

Comment: Pero si quisiera que la ruta sea dinámica, que el usuario la elija, ya que será para una pagina web, y mi ruta no seria las misma en todas las computadoras, gracias de antemano

Comment: aunque obtuvieras la ruta por medio del usuario el archivo seria guardado en el servidor no en la computadora del cliente. eso es lo que quieres ??

Comment: No, el archivo debería ser guardado en la computadora del usuario

Comment: Por desgracia tu no puedes controlar la computadora del cliente, ni la ruta donde debe guardar los archivo desde php. ya que esta configuración de descargas esta proporcionada por el navegador. mas que nada esto es por cuestiones de seguridad del cliente.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, aunque me diste una idea, antes de generar el archivo txt, solicitare la ruta y la enviare con POST, después solo concateno con el nombre del archivo y en teoría debería funcionar